# HTML For Loop to add Image from Django Database

Tags: html, django, for-loop

I am working on passing through a logo into my html code, however whenever I pass it through into html, a little blue question mark appears instead. I was wondering how to pass through the logo into the src. Thanks for the help.

```
  class LoansOutstanding(models.Model):
     company_name = models.CharField("Company Name", max_length=50, default="")
     company_logo_url = models.ImageField("Company Logo", upload_to="main/None", height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Views.py

```
    def number(request, number):
       loans_in_security = LoansOutstanding.objects.filter(number=number)


       return render(request,
              template_name='main/number.html',
              context={"loans_in_securities": loans_in_security})
```

HTML

```
      <div class="profile-details">
        <div class="profile-image-pane">


          <ul>
          {% for loans in loans_in_securities %}
            {% if forloop.first %}

            <li><img class="profile-image" src="{{loans.company_logo_url}}"/></li>
            {% endif %}

          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image url in the html tag must point to `<field_name>.url`. Thus in your case:

```
src="{{loans.company_logo_url.url}}"
```

More precisely, have an if condition to check if the image exists or not, like this:

```
{% for loans in loans_in_securities %}
        {% if loans.company_logo_url %}

        <li>
          <img class="profile-image" src="{{loans.company_logo_url.url}}"/>
        </li>
        {% endif %}

      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey, this still isn't working. Don't know why it isn't working. It recognizes if a image is associated with the filtered name, but doesn't fill that image into the space, still leaving the little blue question mark. Thanks for the help, if you have any other suggestions it would be appreciated!

Comment: Change your image field to company_logo_url = models.ImageField("Company Logo", upload_to="main/Logo", blank=True, null=True)